# Laravel 4 - Validation

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Somewhere I found that validation needs to be done in controller and somewhere in model. Which is a best way?

Are you use a model just for storing data in database or for more things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Best way" is from user to user. We all think differently.

In my case I validate in my controller and have the rules in the model (either as a method or static variable).

```
class ExampleController extends BaseController {
    public function postExample() {
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), Model::getRules(), Lang::get('model.validation'));
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            if (Request::ajax())
                return Response::json($validator->messages()->all());

            return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        }

        // Do stuff here if validation passes.
    }
}
```

```
class Model extends Eloquent {
    public static function getRules() {
        return [
            'image' => ['required', 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,gif,png']
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Laravels Design you are indeed not limited in your choice where to validate your data.

You already talked about two options. I will go about those and show you some more possibilities.

## Controller Validation

When practicing Controller Validation you will basically want to instantiate a validator in your controller methods.

```
<?php

class RegistrationController {
    
    public function getRegister()
    {
        $rules = [
            'username' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|min:8',
            'email'    => 'required|email|unique:users'
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

        if( $validator->fails() )
        {
            // Oh noes. Return a Response for proper error handling
        }

        // Everything is okay
    }

}
```

Although it's pretty simple to get this one running, it's not the best approach. If you take a Controller as what it is, the only thing it should do is, to receive a request, delegate tasks according to the request and then generate a response.

What we are doing using this approach is to bloat up our controller with a task, that is not it's responsibility. Namely: Validating data.

**Pro's**

- Very easy to set up

**Con's**

- Violates the Single-Responsibility-Principle
- Violates Fat Model thin Controller
- Controllers get bloated very quickly

## Model Validation

Fortunately Controller Validation is not our only option. We can also take care of our validation in our model. The big advantage of this method is that the model can control it's own state. Meaning: You would not be able to save a model if it's data is invalid.

Also we are decluttering our controllers. Let's have a look

```
<?php 

class ValidationModel extends Eloquent 
{
 
    protected $rules = [];
    protected $errors;

    protected function isValid()
    {
        $validator = Validator::make( Input::all() , $this->rules );

        if( $validator->fails() )
        {
            $this->errors = $validator->errors;
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function getErrors()
    {
        return $this->errors;
    }

    public function save()
    {
        if( ! $this->isValid() )
            return false;

        parent::save();
    }

}
```

It's a pretty basic example but now you could let your models extends `ValidationModel` and you would have made sure that your model is validated before saving. You get the idea.

**Pro's**

- Pretty DRY since you can extend Eloquent and have your very own `ValidationModel`
- Controllers will automatically be decluttered
- Models can take care of their states by themselves

**Con's**

- SRP is still being violated. Instead of just being an Active Record Class your model now gained the power of validation
- Validation is not reusable

## Validation as a Service

So now that we have this awesome Model Validation option everything else is nonsense right? Not so fast, let's take a look on another one: **Validation as a Service**.

This one is one of my favorites. By implementing Validation as a Service you are hacking together chunks of reusable validation components.

With the power of Laravels IoC-Container you can inject your Validation Service where you need it and keep your controllers and models clean at the same time.

Sounds awesome? It is. Let's hit the road.

```
<?php

interface ValidatorInterface 
{
    public function isValid();
    public function getErrors();
}

abstract class Validator implements ValidatorInterface {

    protected $data;
    protected $errors;

    public function __construct( $data )
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function isValid()
    {
        $validator = Validator::make( $this->data, $this->rules );

        if( $validator->fails() )
        {
            $this->errors = $validator->errors;
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }

    public function getErrors()
    {
        return $this->errors;
    }


}
```

Here's the class all your concrete Validators (validation use cases) will extend. You only need to specify the `$rules` property in them and you are good to go.

Then you can just resolve the Validator via the IoC-Container or any other way you can imagine.

**Pro's**

- Very DRY
- Reusable
- Is conform to the Single-Responsibility-Principle

**Con's**

- A bit of patience is needed since you need to create your abstract class and all your concrete validation classes

## Validation with Hexagonal Architecture

That's not the end of the road. As I said you're free to choose your prefered method. The last one we will take a look at is pretty advanced and I will not go into detail here since that would be too broad.

Instead take a look on [this great post by Chris Fidao](http://fideloper.com/hexagonal-architecture) and especially the validation approach used here. That's sick stuff and defenitely the way to go when building enterprise level applications!

The point I want to make up with my answer is: You are free in your choice, and that's the best about all that.

## Resources

Some parts of this answer were inspired by great developers. You might want to take a look at articles from them.

- http://daylerees.com/trick-validation-within-models
- http://culttt.com/2013/07/29/creating-laravel-4-validation-services/

Answer (score 2):

I started doing it on the controller when I was first learning, but that means that if you need to create models from a different location, you have to duplicate the validation rules and logic.

Some suggest using separate classes for validation, which may be good in some situations, but for my purposes I found that doing validation within the model was a better option. There are a couple of ways to do this, but the easiest by far is to use [Ardent](https://github.com/laravelbook/ardent), which is a drop-in replacement for Eloquent and includes validation out of the box.